# Does the hairy ball theorem follow from Borsuk-Ulam?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The proofs I have seen for the hairy ball theorem all use either degree
of a map defined in e.g. by homology or direct computations using stereographic projections in order to use homotopy arguments in $\mathbb R^2$.

Isn't there a trick to deduce the theorem from the Borsuk-Ulam theorem for the sphere $S^2$?

Answer (score 3):

This is unlikely, since Borsuk-Ulam works for all $n$. Such an argument could not work for, say, the 3-sphere, since the latter can indeed be combed.  In fact $S^3$ is parallelizable.  This follows for example from the fact that $S^3$ is a Lie group, for example that of unit quaternions.

Comment: Is this really an argument? It would be enough to prove (without degree theory) that the identity on $\mathbb S^2$ is not homotopic to the antipodal map. Of course, dimension 2 is crucial.

Comment: The argument you just mentioned is fine, but where does it use Borsuk-Ulam?

Comment: I hope that via some trick Borsuk-Ulam could prove that.

Answer (score 1):

This is indirect, but maybe it will be helpful to you:

- as pointed out in the paper ["A Borsuk-Ulam Equivalent that Directly Implies Sperner’s Lemma"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.04.346) (also [available here](http://www.willamette.edu/~knyman/papers/Fan_Sperner.pdf)) by Nyman and Su, the Borsuk-Ulam theorem implies Sperner's lemma.
- then ["The hairy ball theorem via Sperner's lemma](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4145162) (also [here](http://www.math.byu.edu/~jarvis/sperner.pdf)) by Jarvis and Tanton use Sperner to prove the hairy ball theorem (for $S^2$, not for general $S^{2n}$). Perhaps their proof is due to Shashkin (see their references), but I haven't checked.

Comment: As you say, this is rather indirect and looks like the *logical* implication Borsuk-Ulam $\Rightarrow$ Sperner $\Rightarrow$ Hairy Ball. It is not yet the "little trick" I was hoping for. Nevertheless, thanks for your answer.